# Has this concept already been created/discovered?

Tags: calculus

I discovered the formula $m = -\frac{(1-n\ln(1+i))}{\ln(1+i)}$ explained below:

The idea is that you have two populations, let's say $a$ and $z$, then a given growth rate, $i$, and a given number of periods, $n$. $m$ is the period at which population $z$ is maximized by stopping growth ($i$) on population $a$, (we can call the ending population of $a$ population $b$) and for $n-m$ periods flowing the "offspring" of population $b$ into population $z$ by rate $i$.

The intuition is that to maximize population $z$, there is a point that best maximizes the benefit of compound growth in balance to the cost of losing periods for the "flows".

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: If not, then you may have just handed them the topic for their Ph.D. thesis. Imitation is the sincerest form of flattery, so it wouldn't be all bad necessarily.

Comment: @HankIgoe I suppose the hope is that if it really is a new concept, the timestamp of this posting will ultimately keep my claim on the credit.

Comment: @intuiting_math Of course. All jokes aside, I have not heard of that, so perhaps you are onto some original research. Whatever the case, thanks for posting, and welcome to math.se